# How does a vector<T> get resolved as a function parameter for a templated function?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a helper function that creates an `Array_Ref` obj. The function has a parameter, `vector<t>` - that the compiler is complaining about. I'm using VS2010.

- I put the function in a `.h` by itself.
- I put the function in `Array_Ref.h`
- I put it in a `.cpp` file.
- I put `typename` in `front of vector<T>`
- I put `typedef typename` in front of `vector<T>`

Nothing seems to work.

---

```
#include <vector>
template<class T>
Array_Ref<T> make_ref(vector<T> &v, int s)
{
    return (v.size()) ? Array_Ref<T>(v,s): Array_Ref<T>(0,0);
}
```

I'm getting:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed.
error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
error C2059: syntax error : '<'
```

---

However, putting this in the same header file as `Array_Ref.h` works just fine:

```
template<class T,int size>
Array_Ref<T> make_ref(T (&p)[size])
{
    return (p) ? Array_Ref<T>(p,size): Array_Ref<T>(0,0);
}
```

Comment: vector resides in the std namespace I believe. Try adding std:: before vector

Comment: What is int s parameter for? Also, as others pointed out - we do not know what is Array_Ref. Maybe it also exists in its own namespace and should be qualified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `std::vector`, not `vector`. Also, you don't appear to have defined `Array_Ref` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. stupid mistake on my part. I added the std:: and it worked.

Comment: Hmm spoke too soon -- apologies.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the `std` namespace is missing ? Change `vector` to `std::vector` (avoid using namespace directives in header files).